# Running an application installed on a remote machine through the browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, remote-access

I have written a C++ program in Visual Studio 2010 and

now I would like to ask someone in a different country

to connect to my Win7 laptop and run the program.

I would like them to use their browser to access my program.

Context: a little prototype for an international study; i.e.

I write a program and ask a number of users in different countries

to participate and run my program, so that I can collect some data.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome Remote Desktop
Its same as rdesktop, but works via browser - they will have to install the extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

Note: This might same as they installing rdesktop locally

Comment: So, the participants would definitely have to install "something", correct? There is no way to include not-tech-savvy people in such global surveys that would require some app to run on my machine?

Comment: Nothing I can think right out of my mind
One workaround can be host the program somewhere, build the web interface to take arguments and run the program in background and return the results back to user.
But that won't be possible in your local machine unless you have a static IP or a website hosting (Though you might find cheap/free hosting solutions easily)